# Image generator like https://www.randomlists.com but with API

Tags: image-generation

I'm looking for a random image generator like the one in https://www.randomlists.com/things however I would like to use it in my web app so I need one with a API.

Any possible candidates?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking closer at the website code, the best things to do may be to use their API the way they did.

First, get data for the list by getting this JSON. There is a list of available images in the JSON at `RandL.items`.

https://www.randomlists.com/data/things.json

Then, pull images from the site as given in the list like this (substituting the images names in the `items` list.

https://www.randomlists.com/img/things/phone.jpg